# Remove white space in the array elements with trim not works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this array:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "juego de tronos"
  1 => "tagaryen"
  2 => "house targaryen"
  3 => "casa targaryen"
]
```

and I want get this result:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "juegodetronos"
  1 => "tagaryen"
  2 => "housetargaryen"
  3 => "casatargaryen"
]
```

I´m using this function but not works: `array_map('trim',$myarray)`

Comment: trim removes space from ends for this you have to use loop and replace space ' ' with ''.

Comment: [trim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the __beginning__ and __end__ of a string; use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove spaces from the middle of a string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`trim()` only removes whitespace from the beginning and the end. You probably want

```
array_map(function($a){ 
    return str_replace(' ', '', $a); 
}, $myarray);
```

Answer (score 2):

We have done this

please try the below code. working fine. i have checked.

```
$array1 = array(
            "0" => "juego de tronos",
            "1" => "tagaryen",
            "2" => "house targaryen",
            "3" => "casa targaryen"
        );
        $newArray = array();
        foreach ($array1 as $data){
            $data = str_replace(" ","",$data);
            $newArray[]=$data;
        }
```

Comment: instead of appreciating a good answer, posting a non-good answer is not really good. Check the last one and you will learn something new

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayWithSpace = array(
    "juego de tronos", 
    "tagaryen", 
    "house targaryen", 
    "casa targaryen"
);

$arrayWithoutSpace = array_map(function($value){ 
     return str_replace(' ', '', $value); 
}, $arrayWithSpace);

print_R($arrayWithoutSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` function...

```
$array = [
  "juego de tronos"
  "tagaryen"
  "house targaryen"
  "casa targaryen"
];

$result = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $array);
```

and this will be the result:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "juegodetronos"
  1 => "tagaryen"
  2 => "housetargaryen"
  3 => "casatargaryen"
]
```

more info here: [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)